# How to use Datamapper in conjunction with Heroku Scheduler?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I have a Postgres database that I manipulate using Datamapper on my ruby web server. I am trying to incorporate Heroku Scheduler to update parts of the database every 10 minutes. However when it tries to execute the script it keeps giving this error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/repository.rb:72:in `adapter': Adapter not set: default. Did you forget to setup? (DataMapper::RepositoryNotSetupError)
```

The database is initialized when the server starts up, so why can't this script update the database like I would normally do in the rest of the code.

For example the script being called by the scheduler will contain lines such as:

```
User.update(:user_x => "whatever")
```

Is there a certain require statement I absolutely need?

Comment: I believe the scheduler runs separate from your app, so whatever you have in your main app file to setup the connection, you should probably call from your scheduled script.

Comment: That's correct. It will spin up a new dyno, executing the command you specify.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to point the scheduled process to your database, so include the Datamapper.setup, but don't migrate or initialize.

Then you need to read the database. You probably want datamapper to create object models, just like your app uses. I've been using [dm-is-reflective](https://github.com/godfat/dm-is-reflective) for that.

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-is-reflective'
dm = DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  is :reflective
  reflect
end

p User.fields
```